# Getting NSDates from strings on server

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have some Date Strings on server, which I want to parse in my app, get dates and display it on calendar which my app has and not the device calendar.

To do this I am doing it this way

```
    _dateFromatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_dateFromatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    [_dateFromatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; 
    [_dateFromatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];   


    _gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
    [_gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]]; 


    NSDate *historyDate  = [_dateFromatter dateFromString:[data objectForKey:@"dateStringFromServer"]];

    if(historyDate != nil)
    {
         NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [_gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit)fromDate:historyDate];

         NSInteger year  = [weekdayComponents year];
         NSInteger month = [weekdayComponents month];
         NSInteger day   = [weekdayComponents day];

         NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
         [timeZoneComps setYear:year];
         [timeZoneComps setMonth:month];
         [timeZoneComps setDay:day];
         [timeZoneComps setHour:00];
         [timeZoneComps setMinute:00];
         [timeZoneComps setSecond:01];

         NSDate *convertedHistoryDate =[_gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];
    }
```

**I am adding a break point and making some checks when the execution stops at a break point.**

Now here, on server the string is 8-Jul-2014, and If I mouse hover the date I see 2014-07-08 05:30:00 IST, and if I click on info I get 2014-07-08 00:00:00 +0000,

Secondly Now If I change the timezone for NSCalendar and dateformatter to localtime zone and If I check get this 2014-07-08 00:00:00 IST and inside info I get 2014-07-07 18:30:00 +0000

So I am not understanding these two cases. Also I want to know whenever I get dates from server , does time zone matters and what time zone it should be?

Because my users can be in any timezone? so when they sync data they should get whatever dates are present on server. I mean if 8-Jul-2014 is present on server then, if user in US is syncing it should not make it 7-Jul -2014 it should remain 8 -Jul -2014 only.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: What do you mean by "mouse hover the date"?  Using what interface?

Comment: I am using xcode, so If I add a break point and when the code runs and stops at the break point, I can mouse hover the object right

Comment: OK... so please update your question to make that clear to others.

Comment: Hey I have updated it

Comment: Hey @trojanfoe, please help

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Dates, they are actually same represented by different timezone..

```
2014-07-08 05:30:00 IST/+05:30
2014-07-08 00:00:00 +0000

2014-07-08 00:00:00 IST/+05:30 
2014-07-07 18:30:00 +0000
```

You need to set the formatter timezone correct while converting date to string and visa versa...

```
[inputDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];//server timezone
[outputDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];//user's timezone
```

Comment: it has to be your server's timezone... not UTC specifically

Comment: server needs only strings, so it doent matter what timezone,bcoz, server sends me only strings

Comment: It is just the date representation... If both server and user use internet to sync time... Both have same time it is just the manner in which they are displayed matters... 2014-07-08 00:00:00 IST/+05:30 in India is same as 2014-07-07 18:30:00 +0000 in UK...

Comment: So what if user in UK syncs data , whether he will get date as 7 or 8

Comment: get a date string from server (better with timezone), set dateformatter to server's timezone.... convert datestring to date.... then set date formatter to local timezone (user's)... convert date to dateString... you will get server's time in localtimezone

Comment: if date is 2014-07-08 00:00:00 IST it will be 2014-07-07 in UK

Comment: if date is 2014-07-08 00:05:30 IST it will be 2014-07-08 in UK

Comment: Hey, server doesnt give me any timeZone, it justs give me a string

Comment: now that's a problem... don't you know location of server? couldn't it get you a date string with timezone?

Comment: to get the exact offset in time between server's and user's time... if user is in india GMT+05:30 and server in new york GMT-04:00 (currently EDT).... so difference is 09:30 between server and user -- 9:00 AM in New York will be 6:30 PM in India

Comment: I think I am not able to make you undertand my question, anyways thanks for the effort

Comment: ok... nevermind but if you still want to work with the same date as received.... move all date elements to NSDateComponents but setTimeZone to local/system timezone

Comment: @Ranjit Server date is sent from iOS devices ? I mean user selected dates? If so while sending dates to server , you should follow some standard format (time zone - example: UTC etc), convert to string & send to server. So that once receive back you will have to convert in that same standard format  string to date. If you are not sending date string to server from app , then try to get to know about server timezone - which format its storing.